# C Programming: Reading in Data

Tags: c, scanf

In my code I'm attempting to read in words of certain length. However fscanf isn't working for me. I originally was going to dynamically allocate memory using malloc but for convenience i switched to static. My problem is in the copyWords function, near the bottom? What is my problem?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char longestWords[15][100];
char exampleLetters[] = "faeugher";     //These are a group of example letters that will be randomly generated in a previous part of the program
char *fileName = "D:\\webster.txt";     //Dictionary file

//int initialiseWords();    //This was to set my pointers to NULL if I was to use malloc
int copyWords(int val);

int main()  //This function detects how many words there are of each length (maximum length is 8)
{
    int i, j, k;
    long int n[8] = {0};
    char line[10];

    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");

    //initialiseWords();

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
            k = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                for (j = k; j < 8; j++) {
                    if (line[i] == exampleLetters[j]) {
                        k++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
                if (k == i) n[i-1]++;       //These values are incremented everytime a word of that amount of letters is found i.e. n[0]++ when a one letter word is found
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (n[i] != 0) {
            copyWords(i);
            break;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%li ", n[i]);   //This is irrelevant but just to display the amount of each number of words
    }

    return 1;
} 

/*int initialiseWords()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        longestWords[i] = NULL;
    }

    return 1;
}*/

int copyWords(int val)  //This function copies of over the words that have the maximum length
{
    int i, j, k, l;
    char line[15];

    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        l = 0;

        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
            k = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                for (j = k; j < 8; j++) {
                    if (line[i] == exampleLetters[j]) {
                        k++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (k == val + 1) {
                fscanf(fp, "%s", &longestWords[l]);     //MY PROBLEM!!! The data won't read in to longestWords
                l++;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

   return 1;
}
```

Comment: Do avoid using values of uninitialized variables having automatic storage duration, which is indeterminate, or you will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You invoked *undefined behavior* by passing a pointer to object having wrong type to `fscanf()`: `%s` calls for `char*`, but `&longestWords[l]` has type `char (*)[100]`.

Comment: What if `line` in both functions are initialized to zero and `sscanf(line, "%s", longestWords[l]);` is used instead of `fscanf(fp, "%s", &longestWords[l]);` so that unexpected read from the file is prevented?

Comment: `k = val + 1` does an assignment. Are you sure it is what you want?

Comment: You read a line from the file, compute a value of `k` from it, and then conditionally *read the next data from the file*.  This could indeed be what you want to do, but I'm inclined to guess not.  If you want to copy the data you already read, from `line` into `longestWords`, then you're looking for `strcpy()`, not `fscanf()`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks for all the comments. I definitely want k = val + 1 as the condition. What do you mean by your second comment?

Comment: I mean what I wrote. What is what you don't understand?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Unfortunately strcpy() has the same problem for me. I think I have to read in the data first. I'm only a beginner so I'm not certain of the requisites of using strcpy().

Comment: Be careful not to cause buffer overrun. Are you sure the contents in the file is few enough?

Comment: @MikeCAT That &longestWords[l] has type char (*)[100] rather than char*. The file has about 100,000 words. How would I prevent buffer overrun?

Comment: You can prevent buffer overrun by checking if the index is less than the number of elements allocated (assuming the index won't be negative). Example: `if (l < (int)(sizeof(longestWords) / sizeof(*longestWords))) fscanf(fp, "%s", longestWords[l]);`

Comment: `longestWords[l]` has type `char[100]`. Usually arrays in expression are converted to a pointer to the first element of the array, but it isn't converted when it is used as operand of unary `&` operator. Therefore, the type of `&longestWords[l]` is `char(*)[100]`, which is a pointer to `char[100]`.

Comment: @MikeCAT Unfortunately buffer overrun isn't working, nor is the sscanf method.

Comment: @MikeCAT The good [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625941/c-programming-reading-in-data#comment60849294_36625941) prevents overrun in `[l]` (too many words), yet not overruns in too-long-a-word.  Perhaps `fscanf(fp, "%99s", longestWords[l]);`?

Comment: Step 1: Do not mix `fgets( ... fp)` with `fscanf(fp, "%s", ...`.  Best approach: only use `fgets()`.

Comment: Ulysses, [buffer overrun isn't working,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36625941/c-programming-reading-in-data#comment60849878_36625941) is vague.  Provide precisely the input used, the output expected and the results seen will help a great deal.

Comment: @chux The amount of words I wanted to copy didn't exceed the memory of longestWords. I was able to resolve my problem anyway by using a double pointer and assigning memory to that. It works for me now

Comment: Ulysses You can post your own answer below then, rather than leave the post unresolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int amount;
char **longestWords;
char exampleLetters[] = "fdasjfsf";     //These are a group of example letters that will be randomly generated in a previous part of the program
char *fileName = "D:\\webster.txt";     //Dictionary file

int initialiseWords(int num);   //This was to set my pointers to NULL if I was to use malloc
int copyWords(int val);

int main()  //This function detects how many words there are of each length (maximum length is 8)
{
    int i, j, k;
    long int n[8] = {0};
    char line[15];

    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
            k = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                for (j = k; j < 8; j++) {
                    if (line[i] == exampleLetters[j]) {
                        k++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (i = 8; i > 0; i--) {
                if (k == i) {
                    n[i-1]++;
                    break;
               }        //These values are incremented everytime a word of that amount of letters is found i.e. n1++ when a one letter word is found
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (n[i] != 0) {
            initialiseWords(n[i]);
            copyWords(i);
            amount = n[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%li ", n[i]);   //This is irrelevant but just to display the amount of each number of words
    }

    for (i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", longestWords[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

int initialiseWords(int num)
{
    int i;

    longestWords = (char**)malloc(num * sizeof(char*));

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        longestWords[i] = (char*)malloc((9)* sizeof(char));
    }

    return 1;
}

int copyWords(int val)  //This function copies of over the words that have the maximum length
{
    int i, j, k, l;
    char line[15];

    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        l = 0;

        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
            k = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                for (j = k; j < 8; j++) {
                    if (line[i] == exampleLetters[j]) {
                        k++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (k == val + 1) {
                    strcpy(longestWords[l], line);      //MY PROBLEM!!!
                    l++;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 1;
}
```

I decided to change longestWords to a double pointer. Then I assigned memory to this pointer based on how many words where in the array of that type e.g. if there were 3 eight letter words (n[7]), I would assign three pointers to the the double pointer, in which I then assigned pointers with 9 chars. This allowed me to strcpy() line into longestWords and print them.